# Schedule oozie sub-workflows at different times from parent workflow

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have an Oozie workflow that consists 4 sub-workflows. I need to configure oozie in such a way that

1. the parent workflow runs every 4 hours
2. sub-workflow 1 and sub-workflow 2 runs every 4 hours.
3. sub-workflow 3 should only run every 12 hours.
4. sub-workflow 4 should only run once in a day

I could not able to find any property with oozie coordinator or workflows that could help me schedule my workflow as mentioned above. Wondering what would be the best approach to achieve the same?

Comment: It sounds like they should each have their own coordinator.

Comment: You could pass "nominal time" of execution from Coordinator to Workflow, then use a _Decision_ to start, or not, sub-workflows 3 depending on the time range. Same for sub-w 4.

Comment: I can use a bundle of 4 coordinators. Alternatively there is way to use decision actions to check the timing of workflows and trigger them when condition is satisfied. thanks